# Establishing a Connection to Derby

Tags: derby

I'm trying to establish a connection to a Derby database using the code below.

```
static {
  try  { 
    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
  } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

However, when I run it, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

I understand that it cannot find the Derby driver, and is a classpath error. However, I have copied all the Derby .jar files into my project's /lib folder, and I don't understand what is missing. Help anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your project's lib folder isn't in the classpath.

The error says that derbyclient.jar was not found in the classpath.

Comment: How do I add derbyclient.jar to the classpath?

Comment: Well, there are many ways to do that. It's kind of a basic feature of programming in Java. Here's a good place to start learning about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)